# Compiling curl-sys on x86_64-pc-windows-gnu fails with undefined reference to '__imp___acrt_iob_func'

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm trying to install `wasm-pack` on Windows using the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` target (can't use `msvc`) and the build fails because of a linker error (`undefined reference to '__imp___acrt_iob_func'`).

After a little research I found [this issue](https://github.com/alexcrichton/curl-rust/issues/239), so I changed my `.cargo/config`.

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"
ar = "c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ar.exe"

[target.i686-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "c:/msys64/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe"
ar = "c:/msys64/mingw32/bin/ar.exe"
```

But the problem persists. Is there anything else to be done here?